# Having trouble booting into Ubuntu on macbook air (mid-2012)

Tags: boot, macbook

so I am extremely new to all this, so please excuse my ignorance:)

I have a macbook air (mid 2012) and I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 via usb and I'm having trouble with it all.

I've installed rEFInd and have a live usb made through mac linux usb loader, but when I try to boot into Ubuntu it gives me a "you must install the kernel first" error, then continues to boot later telling me that no live usb host could be found.

Anyone have any advice on the subject? Not sure what to do next.

Comment: @Tim Please, give me exact link to the source what you mean.

Comment: @Masi Comment is no longer relevant for recent versions of ubuntu.

Comment: @Tim Please, explain why.

Comment: @Masi afaik there are no longer mac versions.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have downloaded the Ubuntu AMD 64 bit image and then use the instructions on the Ubuntu download page to write the ISO onto the USB drive using OS X.

It's all command line, but I find that way always works. Refind picks it up. If it doesn't, just hold option for the Mac boot loader to find it.

Comment: This is more like a comment and like link-only answer. Please, provide exact steps how to do the things.